# Replacing popen2 module with subprocess module

Tags: python

How would I correct this code to use subprocess module to replace popen2?

```
popen3 = popen2.Popen3(cmd, capturestderr=True)     
rc = popen3.wait()
if os.WIFEXITED(rc):
    rc = os.WEXITSTATUS(rc) 
        if rc < 0:
            #""" Needed to make sure that catastrophic errors are not processed here, hence the rc check.
            #"""                                             
            if len(stderr) > 0:
                inserts= []
                inserts.append("Warnings occurred during run of %s" % self.__MODULE_NAME )
                inserts.append("Check conversion parameters.")
                #self.msgWrite( "98000001", inserts )

        if rc == 0:
    self.msgDebug("CompartService exited normally", "Exit code with signal: %s" % str(rc))
    #
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple,

```
import subprocess

# the process
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# getting different parts of it.
stdout = proc.stdout.read()
stderr = proc.stderr.read()
rc = proc.wait()
```

---

Specifically to what your code looks like now:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(cmd, stderr=PIPE)
rc = proc.wait()
# the rest of your code
```

Comment: Your example will deadlock if there is significant traffic on stderr. Popen.communicate() should be used instead.

Comment: This is true, but the OP doesn't even use it. I was just demonstrating  subprocess.Popen.

Comment: But you are demonstrating incorrect usage. It deadlocks regardless of whether OP uses it. Just change it to communicate and we all go home happy.